# SQLite for Excel Support 64-bit Excel

Tags: excel, sqlite, vba, 64-bit

I need read data SQLite into Excel. And I found a few solution at ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346979/how-do-i-access-sqlite-from-vba), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630035/whats-the-best-way-to-access-an-sqlite-database-in-microsoft-excel)). I choose `SQLite for Excel` of @Govert. My excel is 64bit version, so i've downloaded and replaced sqlite3.dll(32bit) by sqlite3.dll(64bit) then update the VBA declares:

`...Declare Function...` change to `...Declare PtrSafe Function...`

But I'm still cannot run demo Module1.MyTestSQlite in `SQLiteForExcel.xls` . And error output in `VBE Immediate Window`:

> SQLite3Initialize Error Loading
>   C:\Users\davuz\Downloads\SQLiteForExcel-0.7\Distribution\SQLite3_StdCall.dll:
>   193  Error Initializing SQLite. Error: 193

How to fix sqliteforexcel to run with Excel 64bit?
Thank for help?

Comment: Can you upload an Excel with what you've got so far? I've used SQLite with Excel in the past and it worked perfectly. Unfortunately, I have left all the source code at my previous job, but if you want I can take a look to what you've got...

Comment: Never mind that, it seems that I'm running a 32bit Office at this place so I will be unable to test properly. Sorry!

Comment: @KimGysen Thank you! I'm run test on 32bit Office perfect too. I just want make my addin compatible with both 64bit and 32bit platform. Maybe I have to give up this intention

Comment: That would be a good intention. However, personally I don't think that many are running a 64bit Office version. Even MS advises to run the 32bit Office on a 64bit Operating system to avoid compatibility issues. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA010369476.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I (the [SQLite for Excel](http://sqliteforexcel.codeplex.com) guy) haven't actually tried to figure out the 64-bit VBA declarations yet - I just noted that there is now a pre-compiled SQLite library for 64-bits, which helps us a lot.

First thing to note is that for the 64-bit case you don't need the SQLite3_StdCall.dll intermediate at all. It is just required for 32-bit case where the calling conventions need remapping. So for 64-bit all the .dll references in the VBA file must directly refer to SQLite3.dll.

Next, I think you are on the right track with the PtrSafe changes. But I am not sure exactly how the VBA 64-bit pointers declarations work. One would also have to figure out which of the 'Long' arguments are actually pointers.

So there's still a bit to do...

**Edit:**

**Done. The updated version 0.8 of SQLite for Excel now includes the VBA declarations for 64-bit Excel, updated tests and a copy of the 64-bit SQLite3.dll.**

Comment: Thank you! I think I will try with directly import sqlite3.dll.

Comment: But I'm not clearly about using dll in VBA; Do it through steps:

1) Init sqlite3 by  `LoadLibrary(libDir + "SQLite3.dll")` 
2) Declare functions here http://sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html to use?

Do I follow right steps?

Comment: Yes, but all those Declares in the VBA file need to be fixed, with LongPtr in the right places, and all the handles need to change to LongPtr instead of Long.

Comment: OK - you can try the Version 0.8 on http://sqliteforexcel.codeplex.com now. I've added the 64-bit support.