# Is there a way to convert a .xlsx file that has multiple tabs into a .sqlite file?

Tags: excel, sqlite

I have a .xlsx file with 7 tabs. I need to convert it into a .sqlite file, so I can then join each table on each other to make 1 condensed table. Is there a way to convert the file format without losing data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert your data to SQLite.

## Export tab delimited data; import in SQLite

One way is to export each tab individually as tab delimited data. If your data looked like this for first tab (and you called your file mydata.txt):

```
name    age    created
matt    21     1/1/2020
john    45     2/2/2020
```

You can use SQLite and import it like so:

```
C:\> sqlite3 yourdb.sqlite
sqlite> create table test (name, age, created);
sqlite> .separator "\t"
sqlite> .import mydata.txt test
```

Repeat that with the other 6 tabs and you'll have your data in SQLite.

## Using VBA/tools

These articles can help you use VBA to migrate data into SQLite.

- https://www.codeproject.com/articles/586361/using-an-access-mysql-postgresql-or-sqlite-databas
- [How do I access SQLite from VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346979/how-do-i-access-sqlite-from-vba)
- https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-excel-to-sqlite-online

Comment: Prefer `.mode tabs` over list mode with a custom `.separator` when working with tsv data.